# Angular JS ng-click action function as string

Tags: string, angularjs, action

I am creating an application where the site menu would be dynamically loaded from JSON file. Each menu may correspond to an action that would be defined inside the `ng-click` directive. This would look something like this

```
<li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuContainer.menus" class="{{menuItem.cssClass}}">        
    <a href="{{menuItem.url}}" ng-click="{{menuItem.clickAction}}">    
    <i class="{{menuItem.iconClass}}"></i>{{menuItem.name}}

<span class="badge">{{menuItem.subMenus.length}}</span>
    </a>`enter code here`
<li>
```

Now the problem is `ng-click` does not recognize the `clickAction` as a function, I believe this is due to linking process. I want to know is there any way to evaluate a string to method. I tried do `$eval` but it executes the function on load.

How do I do this?

Comment: Don't use html escape sequences in code, press ctrl+K instead to turn it into quoted code.

Comment: Note that your closing `<li>` should be `</li>`

Answer (score 2):

Define methods not as strings, but as functions and replace `ng-click="{{menuItem.clickAction}}"` to `ng-click="menuItem.clickAction()"`. Another way to define function on $scope, like:

```
$scope.executeString = function(body){
  eval(body);
};
```

and replace your ng-click to `ng-click="executeString(menuItem.clickAction)"`. Anyway, use eval is antipattern;)

Remember, that `ng-click` and other directives, like that, takes angular expression as parameter. And if body of you expression is `a = b + c` than angular convert it in javascript like `$scope.a = $scope.b + $scope.c`