# Passing string to ng-click

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

I've really trying working this out but with no success so far.

the view:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
<div ng-click="action()" class="nav-link">Click me for an action in scope  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is basically to replace "action()" with a variable that I send from a service that modifies rootScope.

in the service:

```
 $scope.myAction = function() {
     $scope.$broadcast("actionEvent");
  }
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
<div ng-click="myAction()" class="nav-link">Click me for an action in scope  </div>
</div>
```

But when I try to replace it, ng-click does not recognize the action. The text is displayed fine, however the action is not execute.

Any idea how it is possible to add this action from the rootScope so that it executes in ng-click?

Looking forward to your answers, thank you !

Btw, I've tried these options:

1) [angular.js parsing value in ng-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010955/angular-js-parsing-value-in-ng-click)
2) [Angular JS ng-click action function as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202483/angular-js-ng-click-action-function-as-string)

Comment: is myAction inside the service?

Comment: yes it is in the service. sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

If your function only needs access to rootScope, you don't need the scope function to be inside the service. Simply inject rootScope into the controller then use it.

```
module.controller("myctrl", function($scope, $rootScope){
 $scope.myAction = function() {
     $rootScope.$broadcast("actionEvent");
  };
});
```

If your function does something with the service, make the function a member of the service, then use the service in your ng-click.

```
module.service("MyService", function($rootScope){
 this.myAction = function() {
     $rootScope.$broadcast("actionEvent");
     // other stuff
  };
});
```

in your controller

```
module.controller("myctrl", function($scope, MyService){
    $scope.ms = MyService;
});
```

in the markup

```
<div ng-click="ms.myAction()" class="nav-link">Click me for an action in scope  </div>
```

Note that it doesn't make sense to inject `$scope` into a service, it simply doesn't have a scope. `$rootScope` is different since it is another service, which your service can depend on. Also note that you shouldn't do `$scope.myAction = MyService.myAction` this might cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try integrate it in the application to see how that works out. The service is injected in every controller to set different data for every page that uses the controllers.